# python, square root simplification function

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a function in python that will simplify the number into an integer under the root. For example:

- √(27) = 3 √(3)
- √(567) = 9 √(7)

I have written the following function, but it's working partially, as I think the while loop isn't effective.
Any help please?

```
def sqrt2(num):
    numbers=[]
    roots=[]
     #i=1-11
    while num>1:    
        for i in range(1,num+1):
            if num%i==0:    
                num=num//i  
                if num%i==0: 
                    num=num//i
                    numbers.append(i)
                else:
                    roots.append(i)
        break

    result=1
    for i in numbers:
        result= result*i
    u_root=1
    for j in roots:
        u_root=u_root*j

    print (result,"sqrt (",u_root,")")
```

Answer (score 2):

This loop simply tries division by 2*2, 3*3, 4*4, etc. until it finds a divisor or until the divisor is too large for the divided number.

The only interesting part is the recursion. If a partial result is found, we try to simplify the smaller number. E.g. 567 = (3*3)*63, and then 63 = (3*3)*7. These two results combined give (9*9)*7.

```
def my_sqrt(num):
    for i in range(2, num):
        div, mod = divmod(num, i*i)
        if mod == 0:
            sq1, sq2 = my_sqrt(div)
            return (i * sq1, sq2)
        if div == 0:
            break
    return (1, num)

print(my_sqrt(27))
print(my_sqrt(567))
```

Answer (score 2):

here's my little code made for math homework

```python
def sqr_sim(und_root):
    und_root = int(und_root)
    und_root0 = round(und_root)
    rt_fc = []
    coef = 1
    if und_root < 0:
        return None
    elif und_root == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        for i in range(2, und_root0):
            if und_root%(i**2) == 0:
                rt_fc.append(i)
                und_root /= i**2

                for i0 in range(2, und_root0):
                    if und_root%(i0**2) == 0:
                        rt_fc.append(i0)
                        und_root /= i0**2

        for ele in rt_fc:
            coef *= ele
        print('the final solution is',
              coef, '√', und_root)

sqr_sim(input())
```

Comment: Why the double loop? `for i in range(2, und_root0): ... for i0 in range(2, und_root0): ...`

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please don't just dump code as an answer. Explain your train of thought so we can better understand what you've done. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your indentation is actually as it appears in the question, your `break` statement needs to be indented more. It should be breaking out of the `for` loop when the first `if` is hit, not breaking out of the `while` loop.

But there's another issue with the code. You're starting the `for` loop with `i` being `1`, but `num % 1` will always be true in that case, leading to an infinite loop. You should skip `i=1` and loop on `range(2, num+1)`:

```
while num>1:    
    for i in range(2,num+1):  # start range with 2
        if num%i==0:    
            num=num//i  
            if num%i==0: 
                num=num//i
                numbers.append(i)
            else:
                roots.append(i)
            break  # increase indent on this line by two levels!
```

Comment: But it sill doesn't get all dividers. It skips a number if present 4 times.

Comment: It shouldn't. If you break out of the `for` loop, it will restart with `i` being `1` and count back up to the `i` value that was being matched again. That's perhaps not terribly efficient, but it will work.

Comment: Ah, there was another bug where `1` was aways being found as a divisor. Skipping 1 and starting with 2 avoids an infinite loop.