# Find simplified square root in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, math, algebra, square-root, simplification

I would like to take a number like 96, call `squareRoot(96)`, and get a return of "4√6". 
I have tried many different versions of

- generating a list of the prime factors
- finding the perfect divisors
- using recursive implementations
- iterative implementations
- HashMaps
- lists

but nothing seems to work. It is driving me crazy! I can provide the functions I wrote to find the factors, but I don't think they are particularly complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer in python here ([python, square root simplification function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33191193/python-square-root-simplification-function)) and translated it into Kotlin:

```
fun squareRoot(n: Int): Pair<Int, Int> {
    var radical = n
    var coefficient = 1
    for (i in 2..radical) {
        if (radical % (i * i) == 0) {
            coefficient *= i
            radical /= i * i
            for (j in 2..radical) {
                if (radical % (j * j) == 0) {
                    coefficient *= j
                    radical /= j * j
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return Pair(coefficient, radical)
}
```

Comment: Do you need to keep a list of `roots`?  If I'm reading it correctly, you could just update `coefficient` as you go along, and avoid the overhead of the list and its traversal.  (And wouldn't a name such as `radicle` be more meaningful than `number1`?)

Comment: (Might be interesting to extend this to cube &c roots, by providing the power as another parameter?)

Comment: True about the list. Edited.

Comment: You should accept your own answer - [nothing wrong with that](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).